# I accidentally enabled tokenization for a large file, how can I disable it?

Tags: tokenize

I was opening a large .csv file and then a popup appeared saying: "tokenization, wrapping and folding have been turned off for this large file in order to reduce memory usage and avoid freezing or crashing."
I didn't think much of it and enabled it, but now everytime I try to open the file the window freezes. Is there a way to disable tokenization for this file?

I tried decreasing the max tokenization line length to disable tokenization for the .csv file. But, despite that nothing changed and it still kept crashing everytime I try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

this can be returned. If you are Mac user, just open the preference settings(command + ,) in the vscode(for example, whatever the IDE just find it), and then search the "Editor: Large File Optimizations", I'm sure you will see the checkbox. If there's still something wrong, feel free to hit me I'm willing to help you.